# How to filter set on sum function in calculation mdx?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

I want to make calculation in olap cube in ssas. This will be "avg sku by outlets".

There is my expression:

```
CREATE 
  MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Avg Prod Art Id Distinct Count By OldcID] AS 
    Avg
    (
      Descendants
      (
        [dimOutlets].[OLDC ID].CurrentMember
       ,[dimOutlets].[OLDC ID].[OLDC ID]
      )
     ,[Measures].[Prod Art Id Distinct Count]
    );
```

It works fine, but when I tried to add some logic to it and something went wrong. I want to filter some docs by status or type.

This is what I did:

```
CREATE 
  MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[test Calculated Member] AS 
    Avg
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          {
            [dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[0]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[1]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[2]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[3]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[7]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].[All].UnknownMember
          }
         ,{
            [dimInvoice].[Status].&[1]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Status].&[2]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Status].&[3]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Status].&[4]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Status].[All].UnknownMember
          }
        )
       ,Descendants
        (
          [dimOutlets].[OLDC ID].CurrentMember
         ,[dimOutlets].[OLDC ID].[OLDC ID]
        )
      )
     ,[Measures].[Prod Art Id Distinct Count]
    ) ;
```

When I try to test this on browser in visual studio, it  thinks for a long time and I do not receive a reply.

Is there a best and fast way to do this?

PS. Sorry about my English.

Comment: Your script looks pretty standard mdx. You could try moving the set into a `CREATE SET` expression and feed that into the calculation - I'll add to a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe move the set out into a named set:

```
CREATE 
  SET CURRENTCUBE.[DocTypes] AS 
    NonEmpty
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          {
            [dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[0]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[1]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[2]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[3]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[7]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].[All].UnknownMember
          }
         ,{
            [dimInvoice].[Status].&[1]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Status].&[2]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Status].&[3]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Status].&[4]
           ,[dimInvoice].[Status].[All].UnknownMember
          }
        )
       ,Descendants
        (
          [dimOutlets].[OLDC ID].CurrentMember
         ,[dimOutlets].[OLDC ID].[OLDC ID]
        )
      );


CREATE 
  MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[test Calculated Member] AS 
    Avg
    (
      [DocTypes]
     ,[Measures].[Prod Art Id Distinct Count]
    ) ;
```

Comment: It is faster, but not as much as I want and there is not and  the result is not correct. Probably in the expression set are not all right.

Comment: You gave me the right idea. The solution works but I changed the code a bit.I add to my answer.

Comment: @user3323059 glad this was some sort of help. Named sets are (I believe) a little like arrays in some other languages in that they occupy a fix area of the computers memory therefore it is much easier for analysis services to reference that memory in subsequent calculations.

Answer (score 1):

This is work (thanks whytheq), but slowly and now i find solution to do this more faster. Wondering whether there is a possibility to do it a measure of the cube?

```
   CREATE DYNAMIC SET CURRENTCUBE.[DocTypesSet]
     AS nonempty
            (
              {
                [dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[0]
               ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[1]
               ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[2]
               ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[3]
               ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].&[7]
               ,[dimInvoice].[Doc Type].[All].UnknownMember
              }
             *{
                [dimInvoice].[Status].&[1]
               ,[dimInvoice].[Status].&[2]
               ,[dimInvoice].[Status].&[3]
               ,[dimInvoice].[Status].&[4]
               ,[dimInvoice].[Status].[All].UnknownMember
              }
             *Descendants
                (
                  [dimOutlets].[OLDC ID].CurrentMember
                 ,[dimOutlets].[OLDC ID].[OLDC ID]
                )
            ) 

  CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[test msr]
  AS Sum(DocTypesSet,[Measures].[Prod Art Id Distinct Count] )
```